# How would I fit a 4 chord progression into 3 bars?

Tags: composition, algorithmic-composition

I'm programmatically trying to create a song. If I have a 4 chord progression that i'm trying to fit into 3 bars, what rules of thumb should i be following to make it sound not terrible?

If we have a example scenario that I'm in the key of C, and my chord progression is I–V–vi–IV. So that leaves us with the chords of C–G–Am–F. What I would do is just shorten the bar the minor chord is in and leave all the major chords longer. Is this a good rule to follow? Will this be ok for other scales, like minor scales?

Sorry if i'm not using the correct terminology, my music theory knowledge is lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chords conventionally change on the bar, on the half bar or on the beat.   Assuming we're in 4/4 time, you could just choose one pair of chords to fill half-a-bar each instead of a full bar.  No reason to treat minor chords any less favourably than major ones!

Comment: So in saying that, would my 3 bar phrase be | I - V | vi - IV | I - V |?  What would  the next 3 bars look like? | vi - IV | I - V |? And if i wanted to round off a nice 8 bar section of song, i'd create a new phrase for the last two bars so that it completes the progression with | V | IV?

Comment: You could do that.   My suggestion was rather to do |I - V| vi | IV |.   Or | I | V | vi -IV |.    It's traditional to end on V or I, depending on whether you're next going to 'go round again' or end.  But you don't HAVE to.